# Why `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse("filename.xml")` method looking for a `XML` file in Operating system's home directory, but not project's

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, servlets

Following `ModifyXML Java class` is used to read an `XML` file and to return all the values of specified tag's "name" attribute.
For below `XML` file it should return a `ArrayList<String>` that cantains `tc_001` and `tc_002`.

```
<root>
    <tc name="tc_001">
    </tc>
    <tc name="tc_002">
    </tc>
</root>
```

First I created the class in a separate `Java` project in `Eclipse` with a main method which creates a new `ModifyXML` object and calls `getTCs()` method using that object. The file structure [is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n44Mb.png). In that project i used directly file path  as "test.xml", which cause no error at run time.

```
public class ModifyXML {

    /*
     * constructor
     * initializing main objects
     */
    public ModifyXML() {

        //this is the file path i used
        filePath = "test.xml";              

        factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = builder.parse(filePath);
    }


    /*
     *getTCs method
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getTCs(String tagType) {
        ArrayList<String> tcList = new ArrayList<>();
        String attributeName = "name";

        NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName(tagType);
        int j = nodes.getLength();

        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
            Node tc = nodes.item(i);
            if(tc.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                String tcName = tc.getAttributes().getNamedItem(attributeName).getNodeValue();
                tcList.add(tcName);
            }
        }

        Iterator<String> iter = tcList.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
            System.out.println(iter.next());

        return tcList;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModifyXML a = new ModifyXML();
        a.getTCs("tc");
    }
```

Then i copied that class to a `Dynamic Web Page` project's `src` folder and `test.xml` file to the `Dynamic Web Page` project, then I removed main method of the class. File structure of `Dynamic Web Page` project [is this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsX3M.png) But when i call `getTCs()` method, in side `servlet`'s `service()` method, an exception is occurred.

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/srinesh/test.xml (No such file or directory)`

I'm using Ubuntu and `/home/srinesh/` is my home directory. My project directory for `Dynamic Web Page` project is `/home/dazz/Projects/workspace/Sanitizor/`. Why that class looking for the `test.xml` file in my home directory only when the class is located in a `Dynamic Web Page` project?

`Servlet` class is showed below.

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter printWriter  = response.getWriter();

    ModifyXML xml = new ModifyXML("test.xml");
    ArrayList<String> tc = xml.getTCs("tc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using relative path is not a good idea, as you see sometimes you may run the project from different directories.
So either use absolute path (`"/some/path/to/your/file/file.xml"`) to the file, or use a classpath to read it, e.g.:

```
document = builder.parse(ModifyXML.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + filePath);
```

In the second case, you have to put the file at the root of your classpath.

Comment: both options didn't work
first : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///home/dazz/Projects/workspace/Sanitizor/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

second: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null

Comment: That error message sounds a bit like there is a problem with your xml file.